# What Sounds Better?

Tags: phrases

Which sounds best?

- Home of many teams
- Home to many of teams
- Home to many teams

It will be written under a logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct would be to say "home to many teams." This StackExchange post seems to back up the choice:

["home to" or "home for"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/home-to-or-home-for)

"Home of many teams" is also grammatically correct, but it is used much less often.

The phrase "many of" describes a partial quantity in a group (for example, "many of these apples are red"), so it would need a qualifier to be grammatically correct. And if it's going below a logo, a short phrase is your best bet.